# How to remove extra space or reduce extra space between navigation back button and page title in xamarin (Android) app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

What to do for removing extra highlighted space or reduce space ? [image]

Comment: I think this goes against the android Material Design

Comment: Hi & welcome to Stack Overflow! This forum is not for questions about technologies or to find somebody doing the work for free (search some freelance service for that). See [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Create Minimal Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for ideas about what kind of questions can be made and [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Actually, to me, this is exactly the type of question that stackoverflow is perfect for, how to do a specific thing, or fix a specific problem. And anyone familiar with Xamarin.Forms knows exactly what this person is asking.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not have an answer off hand.

Comment: I have added my own solution in answer section. Thank you .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Here is my solution to achieve required extra space removal**

In my droid project I have changed values/styles.xml like this

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
</style>
<style name="MyTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
<item name="colorPrimary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primaryDark</item>
<item name="colorAccent">@color/accent</item>
<item name="android:windowBackground">@color/window_background</item>
<item name="android:colorPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:colorLongPressedHighlight">@color/ListViewHighlighted</item>
<item name="android:colorFocusedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:colorActivatedHighlight">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
<item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@color/ListViewSelected</item>
</style>

<style name="homeToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/primary</item>
<item name="windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="contentInsetLeft">12dp</item>
<item name="contentInsetStart">12dp</item>
<item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="homeToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" 
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
<item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">10dp</item>
<item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

In my droid project I have changed values-v21/styles.xml like this

```
<resources>
<style name="MyTheme" parent="MyTheme.Base">
<item name="toolbarStyle">@style/homeToolbarStyle</item>
<item 
name="toolbarNavigationButtonStyle">@style/homeToolbarNavigationButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="homeToolbarStyle" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar">
<item name="titleTextColor">@color/primary</item>
<item name="android:windowActionModeOverlay">true</item>
<item name="android:contentInsetLeft">12dp</item>
<item name="android:contentInsetStart">12dp</item>
<item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/primary</item>
<item name="contentInsetStartWithNavigation">0dp</item>
<item name="android:paddingLeft">10dp</item>
</style>

<style name="homeToolbarNavigationButtonStyle" 
parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Toolbar.Button.Navigation">
<item name="android:minWidth">0dp</item>
<item name="android:scaleType">centerInside</item>
<item name="android:paddingRight">0dp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

In my droid project I have changed values/color.xml like this

```
<resources>
<color name="primary">#ED1C22</color>
<color name="primaryDark">#9b0000</color>
<color name="accent">#ED1C22</color>
<color name="window_background">#FAFAFA</color>
<color name="ListViewSelected">#EEEEEE</color>
<color name="ListViewHighlighted">#EEEEEE</color>
</resources>
```

Here is final output

[image]

Comment: Nice, that extra space has been bugging me for ages :)